# How to make a list from a data frame with first column as a reference?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am still learning R. I wanted to know how to make a list of columns with the first column as a reference. Using `mtcars` as an example:

```
head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

I would like to have

```
$cyl
                   mpg cyl 
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  
Datsun 710        22.8   4  
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  
Valiant           18.1   6  

$disp
                   mpg disp 
Mazda RX4         21.0  160 
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0  160 
Datsun 710        22.8  108 
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4  258 
Hornet Sportabout 18.7  360 
Valiant           18.1  225 
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` and `cbind` 1st column with every other column in `mtcars`

```
lapply(mtcars[-1], function(x) cbind(mtcars[1], x))

#$cyl
#                     mpg x
#Mazda RX4           21.0 6
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0 6
#Datsun 710          22.8 4
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4 6
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7 8
#Valiant             18.1 6 
#....

#$disp
#                     mpg     x
#Mazda RX4           21.0 160.0
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0 160.0
#Datsun 710          22.8 108.0
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4 258.0
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7 360.0
#....
```

This is similar to `purrr::map`

```
purrr::map(mtcars[-1], ~cbind(mtcars[1], .))
```

---

Or using `Map`

```
Map(cbind, x = mtcars[1], y = mtcars[-1])
```

This is similar to `purrr::map2`

```
purrr::map2(mtcars[1], mtcars[-1], cbind)
```

Comment: Getting the names right seems to be a fraction more difficult. Best I could do is `nm <- names(mtcars); 
Map(function(i) mtcars[c(nm[1],i)], nm[-1])`

Comment: @thelatemail yes, with `lapply` I would have done `lapply(names(mtcars)[-1], function(x) cbind(mtcars[1], mtcars[x]))` to get the names.

Comment: That misses the naming of the outside list though.

Comment: arrghhh..right! We can rename the list again though but yess..not so straight forward.